# Is the limit function a Gaussian?

Tags: limits, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

What is the limit of the function $f$ as $a\rightarrow \infty$? The function $f$ is defined as:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = e^{-a(1-x)^{-1}}(1-x)^{-1-a}.
\end{equation}
The function $f$ is the stationary distribution of a stochastic process that, when $a\rightarrow \infty$, it approximates a linear Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process which has a Gaussian invariant distribution. Can we prove that $f$ approaches such Gaussian when $a\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: *Welcome to the site !*. It is your best interest to show what you already did and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Have you considered writing $(1-x)^{-a} = e^{-a\log(1-x)}$ and looking at the saddle point?

Comment: This is a nice rewriting of the function. I'm not sure what you mean with the saddle point, though. I guess one can notice that $-(1-x)^-1$ is the derivative of $\log (1-x)$, but I don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: I mean, bring it to the form $e^{-aF(x)}$ and examine what happens near the minimum of $F$ as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method

Comment: This seems to solve the problem. This was helpful. Thanks.